# Is there a way to search for a value in an Excel spreadsheet and print out what row the value is in using Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am trying to use Python to look for a value in an Excel spreadsheet, and have Python print out the row that value is in.

For example, I know that the number 10 is in a certain column in my spreadsheet, but there are too many rows to search through manually, so I would like to use Python to find out which row it is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for example, if you're looking for "10" in a spreadsheet of various numbers a easy way to solve this is to use the xlrd library and loop through each cell and check if it contains "10"

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
   for col in range(sheet.ncols):
      if sheet.cell_value(row, col) == 10:
         print row, col
```

Keep in mind that this is not the most effective way of doing this. If you have a significant amount of data you could use pandas, import one csv as a "Objective_Table" dataframe and import another as a "Search_Table" and then use the merge feature.

Hope this helps.